# An $R[x]_n$ space with a custom scalar product proves.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, change-of-basis

In the space $R[x]_n$ (polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most $n$) some scalar product is introduced.

I want to prove that in the resulting Euclidean space:

1. There is an orthogonal basis containing one polynomial of each of the degrees from $0$ to $n$.
2. If $e_0,\cdots, e_n$ and $e'_0,\cdots , e'_n$ are two bases satisfying part 1)
   (the numbering corresponds to degrees), then $e_i = \alpha_i e'_i$ for
   some real factors $\alpha_i$

For part 1) I want to say that basis $E = \{e_0, \cdots, e_n\}$ where $e_i = x^i$ gives us what we want, but could't understand why it's true. Maybe someone can give me some strict prove.

For the second part seems like we can say something like: 'if not then the linearity of the scalar product will not be fulfilled when if we transfer vectors from one basis to another'. Also think it can be proved quite easier. Can someone help me with this two cases?

Comment: Your example in 1) will not be orthogonal in general, however you can use that to get an example that will work using the Gram-Schmidt process. For 2) I would use an inductive argument using the fact that $e_0,\dots,e_i$ span the same subspace as $e_0',\dots,e_i'$ for $i=0,\dots,n$

Comment: In $\;2\;$ , I guess you meant to write $\;e_i=\alpha_ie'_i\;$ , and not what is written there.

Comment: @leoli1 can u explain why vectors which we get after using Gram-Schmidt process for $e_0, \cdots, e_n$ is still contains one polynomial of each of the degrees from $0$ to $n$?

Comment: Look at the formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram–Schmidt_process) for the Gram-Schmidt process: In each step we subtract linear combinations of 'previous' terms which will not change the degree (take $v_1=1,\dots,v_{n+1}=x^n$ in the notation in the article)